# C++ : How to assign mandarin (strings) to numbers a user inputed by using an array & Operator Issues

Tags: c++, arrays, operators

Here is my code (Problem Description on the Bottom):

```
int x = 0;
int y = 0;
int z = 0;

const size_t MANDARIN_SIZE = 11;
const char *mandarin[MANDARIN_SIZE] = {" ling "," yi "," er "," san "," se "," wu "," liu "," qi "," ba "," jiu "," shi "};

cout << "Please enter a number that you want to count up to in Mandarin." << endl;
cin >> x;
if (!cin) return 1;
cout << "Please enter what number to start with:" << endl;
cin >> y;
if (!cin) return 1;
cout << "What step size do you want to use?\n";
cin >> z;
if (!cin) return 1;

for ( ; y<=x; y=y+z)
{
    int tens = y / 10;
    int ones = y % 10;
    if ( x < 11 )
        cout << y << mandarin[ones] << "\n";
    if ( x > 10 && x < 19 )
        cout << y << " shi " <<  mandarin[ones] << "\n";
    if ( x >= 20 )
        cout << y << mandarin[tens] << " shi " << mandarin[ones] << "\n"; 
}
```

The goal of the program is to have a user input what number they want the program to count to, what number the counting sequence begins, and the increments it counts in.

When I do 1 - 10, everything is okay until 10 when it puts ling when it's supposed to be shi.

When I do 1 - 11, it adds yi to the beginning to each number.

When I do 11 - 19, it doesn't work.

When I go to 99, it gets even more messy. It also adds ling to the end of every increment of 10 like 10, 20, 30, etc. when it doesn't need that.

So I don't understand what's wrong with the int tens, int ones, and the if statements... also assigning the variable. I am completely blind to what to do. Many kids in my class used if statements, but I jumped right into arrays because I did not want to do 20 if statements.

Please and thank you.

Comment: There are a lot of problems. My advice to you is to use a debugger (or print to console) and watch the values of `tens` and `ones`.

Comment: y varies but you compare x, for example if (x < 11). Are you sure?

Comment: what should i type in the if statements then to make sure the output is what i want?

Answer (score 0):

If understand correctly the way you count in Mandarin, this code will count correctly up to 99. I'm using a std::map here which I think is more appropriate and c++-style than your approach.

```
#include <map>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main () {

  std::map<int,std::string> mandarin_numbers;
  mandarin_numbers[0] = "ling";
  mandarin_numbers[1] = "yi";
  mandarin_numbers[2] = "er";
  mandarin_numbers[3] = "san";
  mandarin_numbers[4] = "se";
  mandarin_numbers[5] = "wu";
  mandarin_numbers[6] = "liu";
  mandarin_numbers[7] = "qi";
  mandarin_numbers[8] = "ba";
  mandarin_numbers[9] = "jiu";
  mandarin_numbers[10] = "shi";

  // in c++11 you could more simply: std::map<unsigned int,std::string,> mandarin_numbers {{0,"ling"}, etc..};

  std::cout << "Please enter a number that you want to count up to in Mandarin." << std::endl;
  int x = 0;
  std::cin >> x;
  std::cout << "Please enter what number to start with:" << std::endl;
  int y = 0;
  std::cin >> y;
  std::cout << "What step size do you want to use?" << std::endl;
  int z = 0;
  std::cin >> z;

  for ( ;y<=x; y=y+z) {
    int tens = y / 10;
    int ones = y % 10;
    std::cout << mandarin_numbers[tens] << " " << mandarin_numbers[10] << " "
          << mandarin_numbers[ones] << std::endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you want to count to 10, starting at one, with a step size of two, your program will output this:
1 yi
3 san
5 wu
7 qi
9 jiu
We will not output anything past bc the next number is over 10.
Dictionary:
0 - ling
1 - yi
2 - er
3 - san
4 - se
5 - wu
6 - liu
7 - qi
8 - ba
9 - jiu
10 - shi
To count numbers over 10, use the following rules:
For numbers 11 through 19, it is shi followed by the digit above:
11 - shi yi
12 - shi er
13 - shi san
For numbers 20 through 99, it is the first digit followed by shi followed by
the second digit (except 0):
33 - san shi san
52 - wu shi er
80 - ba shi

Comment: Sorry I'm still learning how to use this site, but the output on your program is incorrect. It did help me understand the arrays more. The comment above is the directions and how the output should be

Comment: @Alexis you can built upon my program then, the idea is that you use `mandarin_numbers[N]` with N being the digit you want to encode. So you can then put your `if` (or maybe `swich`) blocks within the look and advance from there.